# Knockout if, click and visible binding

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, conditional-statements, visibility

Very simple question.

Say I have this HTML in my view():

```
<a id="btnXYZ" class="" data-bind="click: editAction">Button</a>
```

Simple anchor tag that would execute `editAction` if clicked.

Now if I have something like this:

```
<a id="btnXYZ" class="" data-bind="click: editAction, if: isOwner(ref)">Button</a>
```

Let say `isOwner(ref)` evaluates to true, I see anchor with no text. Not good.

Expected result would be same as before (first example).

And now lets say I have something like this:

```
<div class="">
    <a id="btnX" class="" data-bind="click: editAction, if: isOwner(ref)">Button</a>
    <a id="btnY" class="" data-bind="click: editAction, if: isOwner(ref)">Button</a>
    <a id="btnZ" class="" data-bind="click: editAction, if: isOwner(ref)">Button</a>
</div>
```

Same as before, if isOwner(ref) evaluates to true see empty anchor tags.

**Question:**
How can I bind `if: isOwner()` to manage button visibility?

i.e.
if `isOwner(ref)` evaluate to `true` I should see a proper link/button
if `isOwner(ref)` evaluates to `false` I should see no link/button at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [virtual elements](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) to achieve that:

```
<!-- ko if: isOwner(ref) -->
    <a id="btnXYZ" class="" data-bind="click: editAction">Button</a>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Also if you want you can display something completely different instead like:

```
<!-- ko ifnot: isOwner(ref) -->
    whatever you want
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Don't know how I didn't think of that. Nust have been too tired (to think). Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`visible`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) binding.  This will show and hide the entire element, while the `if` binding just controls the contents of the element.

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fu5ca05t/4/).

However in this case, I would go with @Vladimirs answer as you can wrap the virtual element around all 3 of your buttons, rather than binding them all individually.

Comment: Indeed, ``visibility`` will not allow me to execute isOwner() from the view.